# Format text inside shape in VISO using c#

Tags: add-in, visio, office-addins

Hi I wrote this code for a VISIO addin to create shapes and include text in it, here is a part of the  code

```
visioRectShape.Text = "My text";
            visioRectShape.get_CellsSRC((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionParagraph,
            (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowFirst, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visHorzAlign).FormulaU = "0";
```

now i want to align this text to top and to the left and format the text to make it bold inside the shape.

with the above code I am able to align it to the left but not able to make it bold or align it to the top.
Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the macro recorder to figure out what operations Visio performs to achieve the formatting you want. To do so, click "Start recording", then perform your operations (set text bold, and align to the top), click "Stop recording", and examine the source code generated by the recorder.
You should see something like this:

```
' bold font
shape.CellsSRC(visSectionCharacter, 0, visCharacterStyle).FormulaU = "1"

' align top
Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowText, visTxtBlkVerticalAlign).FormulaU = "0"
```

Using C#

```
// bold font
visioRectShape.get_CellsSRC(
    (short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter,
    (short)0, 
    (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterStyle).FormulaU = "1";

// align top
visioRectShape.get_CellsSRC(
    (short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
    (short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowText, 
    (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visTxtBlkVerticalAlign).FormulaU = "0";
```

Comment: the above code is not working for me in c#. I am getting the following error:
Error 1 The name 'visSectionCharacter' does not exist in the current context  
Error 2 The name 'visCharacterStyle' does not exist in the current context  
Error 3 The name 'visSectionObject' does not exist in the current context  
Error 4 The name 'visRowText' does not exist in the current context  
Error 5 The name 'visTxtBlkVerticalAlign' does not exist in the current context

is there any way how I can make this work?

Comment: Well, this is VBA code. You need to translate that to C#. I think the translation must not be very hard, you can do it by analogy to your code for the left alignment.

Comment: I tried to convert this to c# but was not successful, can you help me out a little. thanks in advance